Why is the GCE ops agent not tailing my log files?
This is my config (/etc/google-cloud-ops-agent/config.yaml):
logging:
  receivers:
    my_logs:
      type: files
      include_paths:
        - /var/log/pods/*.log
        - /tmp/*.log
      # exclude_paths: [/var/log/not-this-one.log]
      record_log_file_path: true

I know its in the right place because when it was malformed the agent failed to start.
Its not tailing logs in "/tmp" or "/var/log/pods". I also didn't see anything in the docs about recursion. Is it recursing through subfolder of "/var/log/pods"? If not how do I do that?
When it starts up it looks like its ignoring my log files:

